# Check if a string can be made from the characters in another string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, performance

I have two strings, string1 and string2. I want to check if string1 can be made up of characters in string2 (without repeating characters"). For instance, if string1 is "tool" and string2 is "atoll", the function will return false. If string1 is "touch" and string2 is "chetoudce", it will return true.

What is the most efficient way to do this in Javascript? I was thinking of using indexOf and then removing the characters that are used from string2 to build string1, but I think creating this auxiliary string might have performance issues.

edit: I made this based on the first response, here it is:

```
function isSubsetOf(a, b){
    if(a.length > b.length){
        return false;
    }

    while(a.length > 0){
        var letter = a.substr(0, 1),
            re = new RegExp(a.substr(0, 1), 'g'),
            a_count = (a.match(re)||[]).length,
            b_count = (b.match(re)||[]).length;

        if(a_count > b_count){
            return false;
        }

        a = a.replace(re, '');
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please see the [performance ratings](http://jsperf.com/stringissubsetof) for all the answers on this page. The fastest all-around so far is my third idea from my answer below, though different browsers/versions have different top winners. – ErikE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, count the characters in each string.  Then, if the superstring has greater than or equal numbers of each character than the substring, return true.

O(m+n), for m and n are the sizes of the substring and superstring.

Example:

```
Superstring: aaaaabbbbccc
Substring: aabbcc

Superstring letters: 
    a: 5
    b: 4
    c: 3
    all others: 0
Substring letters:
    a: 2
    b: 2
    c: 2
    all others: 0

5 >= 2, 4 >= 2, 3 >= 2, so true
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in O(n) time:

```
string1 = "touch";
string2 = "chetoudce";

var chars = {}, l = string2.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) chars[string2[i]] = (chars[string2[i]] || 0)+1;

l = string1.length;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( chars[string1[i]]) chars[string1[i]]--;
    else return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my first idea.

```
function isSubsetOf(elements, set) {
   var i, l = elements.length, pos;
   set = set.split('');
   for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
      pos = set.indexOf(elements.charAt(i));
      if (pos == -1) return false;
      set.splice(pos, 1);
   }
   return true;
}

/*-- Algorithm: --*/
// for each character in *elements*:
//   remove that character from an array of *set*'s characters
//   (and if not found, return false).
```

However, I was not aware that IE does not have `Array.indexOf`, which makes this an awful loser in terms of performance on IE with a standards-compliant `indexOf` function added to `Array.prototype`. To my surprise, however, it just *screams* with Chrome, which apparently is a mean splice-crunching machine.

My second idea works a lot better than my first, but not significantly better than others on the page.

```
function isSubsetOf2(elements, set) {
   var i, l, counts = {};
   for (i = 0, l = set.length; i < l; i += 1) {
      char = set.charAt(i);
      counts[char] = (counts[char] || 0) + 1;
   }
   for (i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i += 1) {
      char = elements.charAt(i);
      if (!counts[char]) return false;
      counts[char] -= 1;
   }
   return true;
}

/*-- Algorithm: --*/
// For each character in *set*:
//    increment its count in an object "map".
// For each character in *elements*
//    decrement its count in an object map
//    (and if < 0 or doesn't exist, return false)
```

So, finally, my third idea is fastest in Firefox and a good all-around contender, though different browsers display quite different profiles of speed for different functions.

```
function isSubsetOf3(elements, sets) {
   var e, s, el = elements.length, sl = sets.length;
   elements = elements.split('').sort();
   sets = sets.split('').sort();
   for (e = 0, s = 0; e < el; e += 1, s += 1) {
      while (s < sl && sets[s] < elements[e]) { s += 1; }
      if (s == sl || sets[s] > elements[e]) { return false };
   }
   return true;
}

/*-- Algorithm: --*/
// Sort arrays of the characters in *elements* and *set*.
// Do a logical "merge join" (cool!) and:
//    if no match is found, return false
// MERGE JOIN:
// For each character in the *elements* array ("left" input)
//    Consume one matching character from *set* ("right" input)
//       (skipping matches that are less than the character)
//    And if *set* runs out of characters or is higher than *element*, return false
```

Merge joins are FAST, if the inputs are sorted. Apparently, sorting two arrays is faster in the browser than doing multiple Regex operations per string.

Edit: I just realized that my idea #2 is basically a duplicate of Kolink's algorithm. However, there is a consistent performance edge in my function. Some interesting results might be found in an analysis of their differences.

Also, I figured out that in #2, I shouldn't have moved `counts[char] -= 1;` up a line, but I don't want to blow away the performance results I've already gotten at jsperf. So I'm leaving it, as it doesn't unfairly skew the results since it can only hurt the performance of the function.

[Do the speed tests yourself at jsperf](http://jsperf.com/stringissubsetof)!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple regex solution. It's very similar to yours, except it doesn't do any string manipulation, so it might be a tiny bit faster.

```
function check(needle, haystack) {

  var visited = {}, chr, i, re;

  for (i = needle.length; i--;) {
    chr = needle[i];
    if (visited[chr])
      continue;
    re = new RegExp(chr, 'g');
    if ((haystack.match(re) || []).length < (needle.match(re) || []).length) 
      return false;
    visited[chr] = true;
  }

  return true;  

}
```

http://jsbin.com/uretim/edit#preview

Comment: @ErikE believe it or not I went back and forth on that a few times ;)

Comment: `stringOfNeedles`, `needleStack`? I also like `recipe`:`ingredients`.